# Using Selenium to find indexed element within a div

Tags: python, selenium, indexing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping the front-end of a webpage and having difficulty getting the HMTL text of a div within a div.

Basically, I'm simulating clicks - one for each event listed on the page.  From there, I want to scrape the date and time of the event, as well as the location of the event.

Here's an example of one of the pages I'm trying to scrape:

https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1013664851-los-grandes-de-la-banda-at-aura-nightclub?came_from=257&utm_medium=web&utm_source=home&utm_campaign=event

```
<div class="eventInfoContainer-54d5deb3">
    <div class="lineupContainer-570750d2"> 
    <div class="eventInfoContainer-9e539994">
        <img src="assets.bandsintown.com/images.clock.svg">
        <div>Sunday, April 21st, 2019</div> <!––***––> 
        <div class="eventInfoContainer-50768f6d">5:00PM</div><!––***––> 
     </div> 
<div class="eventInfoContainer-1a68a0e1">
    <img src="assets.bandsintown.com/images.clock.svg">
    <div class="eventInfoContainer-2d9f07df">
        <div>Aura Nightclub</div> <!––***––> 
        <div>283 1st St., San Jose, CA 95113</div> <!––***––> 
</div>
```

I've marked the elements I want to extract with asterisks - the date, time, venue, and address.  Here's my code:

```
base_url = 'https://www.bandsintown.com/?came_from=257&page='
events = []
eventContainerBucket = []
for i in range(1, 2):
    driver.get(base_url + str(i))

# get events links
event_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class^=eventList-] a[class^=event-]')
# collect href attribute of events in even_list
events.extend(list(event.get_attribute("href") for event in event_list))



# iterate through all events and open them.
for event in events:
    driver.get(event)
    uniqueEventContainer = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class^=eventInfoContainer-]')[0]
   
    print "Event information: "+ uniqueEventContainer.text
```

This prints:

```
Event information: Sunday, April 21st, 2019
3:00 PM
San Francisco Brewing Co.
3150 Polk St, Sf, CA 94109
View All The Fourth Son Tour Dates
```

My issue is that I can't access the nested eventInfoContainer divs individually.  For example, the 'date' div is position [1], as it is the second element (after img) in it's parent div "eventInfoContainer-9e539994".  The parent div "eventInfoContainer-9e539994" is in position [1] is it is likewise the second element in it's parent div "eventInfoContainer-54d5deb3" (after "lineupContainer).

By this logic, shouldn't I be able to access the date text by this code: (accessing the 1st position element, with it's parent being the 1st position element, within the container (the 0th position element)?

```
for event in events:
    driver.get(event)
    uniqueEventContainer = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class^=eventInfoContainer-]')[0][1][1]
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'WebElement' object does not support indexing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you index into webElements list (which is what `find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class^=eventInfoContainer-]')` returns) you get a webElement, you cannot further index into that. You can split the text of a webElement to generate a list for further indexing.

If there is regular structure across pages you could load html for div into BeautifulSoup. Example url:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1013664851-los-grandes-de-la-banda-at-aura-nightclub?came_from=257&utm_medium=web&utm_source=home&utm_campaign=event')
soup = bs(d.find_element_by_css_selector('[class^=eventInfoContainer-]').get_attribute('outerHTML'), 'lxml')
date = soup.select_one('img + div').text
time = soup.select_one('img + div + div').text
venue = soup.select_one('[class^=eventInfoContainer-]:nth-of-type(3) div > div').text
address = soup.select_one('[class^=eventInfoContainer-]:nth-of-type(3) div + div').text

print(date, time, venue, address)
```

---

If line breaks were consistent:

```
containers = d.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class^=eventInfoContainer-]')
array = containers[0].text.split('\n')
date = array[3]
time = array[4]
venue = array[5]
address = array[6]
print(date, time, venue, address)
```

---

With index and split:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1013664851-los-grandes-de-la-banda-at-aura-nightclub?came_from=257&utm_medium=web&utm_source=home&utm_campaign=event')
containers = d.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class^=eventInfoContainer-]')
date_time = containers[1].text.split('\n')
i_date = date_time[0]
i_time = date_time[1]
venue_address = containers[3].text.split('\n')
venue = venue_address[0]
address = venue_address[1]
print(i_date, i_time, venue, address)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, webelements doesn't have indexing. What you are confusing with is list.

Here

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class^=eventInfoContainer-]')
```

This code returns a list of webelements. That is why you can access a webelement using the index of the list. But that element doesn't have indexing to another webelement. You are not getting a list of lists.

That is why 
`driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class^=eventInfoContainer-]')[0]` works.   But `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class^=eventInfoContainer-][0][1]')` doesn't.

---

**Edit:**(Answer for quesion in the comment)

---

It is not slenium code.

The code posted in the answer by [QHarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6241235/qharr) uses `BeautifulSoup`. It is a python package for parsing HTML and XML documents.
`BeautifulSoup` has a `.select()` method which uses CSS selector against a parsed document and return all the matching elements.
There’s also a method called `select_one()`, which finds only the first tag that matches a selector.

In the code,

```
time = soup.select_one('img + div + div').text 
venue = soup.select_one('[class^=eventInfoContainer-]:nth-of-type(3) div > div').tex
```

It gets the first element found by the given CSS selector and returns the text inside the tag. The first line finds a `img` tag then finds the immediate sibling `div` tag, then again finds the sibling dev tag of the previous `div` tag. 
In the second line it finds the third sibling tag that has class starts with `eventInfoContainer-` and then it finds the child `div` and find the child of that `div`.

Check out [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

This could be done directly using selenium:

```
date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[class^='eventInfoContainer-'][src$='clock.svg'] + div")
time = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[class^='eventInfoContainer-'] + div + div")
venue = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[class^='eventInfoContainer-'][src$='pin.svg'] + div > div")
address = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[class^='eventInfoContainer-'][src$='pin.svg'] + div > div:nth-of-type(2)")
```

I've used differnt CSS selectors but it still selects the same elements.
I'm not sure about `BeautifulSoup` but in the answer of QHarr, the date selector would return other value instead of intended value for selenium.

Comment: Thanks for the help here.  Can you please explain how this bit of the code works?  Still not understanding this method in Selenium.                                                time = soup.select_one('img + div + div').text
venue = soup.select_one('[class^=eventInfoContainer-]:nth-of-type(3) div > div').text

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 Updated the answer according to your question.